# How to locally access Apache Airflow webserver on a remote server

Tags: ubuntu, airflow, portforwarding

I have an Ubuntu server where i currently have a number of scripts automated with cron.  I would like to move to Apache Airflow.  I have some experience with Airflow using it locally.  My question is if i can setup airflow on the Ubuntu server but access the web server on my local windows 10 desktop.  If so - how do you do that?  Would I use port forwarding?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Matthew, I dont know if you still in doubt, but, I guess its a matter of port forwarding

On your ubuntu server execute airflow normally, like:

```
airflow webserver -p 8080
```

Airflow will tell you what is the address that its running (usually http://0.0.0.0/8080)

After that, on you windows 10's prompt execute the folling command:

```
ssh -N -f -L localhost:<local port>:localhost:<remoteport> <user>@<remote server address> -p <server port>
```

Hope it helped you :D

Answer (score 0):

Load airflow webserver with hostname 0.0.0.0. For example:

`airflow webserver --port 8080 --hostname 0.0.0.0`

Then point your browser to your remote server IP with port specified:

`http://123.123.123.123:8080`

Remember to check your firewall and or security group allows port 8080.